# How can I include Mathematica code in a document?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to include some Mathematica code in a LaTeX document.

It's along the lines of
`f[a_,b_]:=a^2+b^2+4b^3+25a*b*c ;`

However, when I build my PDF, the `_` and `^` always render. Is there a way to get it to just show up as it shows above?

Comment: See also [formatting - Fanciest way to include Mathematica code in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84748/fanciest-way-to-include-mathematica-code-in-latex?rq=1) — the top answer there seems to have a way to include syntax highlighting/coloring.

Answer (score 21):

As rdhs mentionned, you can use the listings package. A sample example is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{[5.2]Mathematica}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
f[a_,b_]:=a^2+b^2+4b^3+25a*b*c ;
\end{lstlisting}

For inline stuff you can use \lstinline$f[a_,b_]:=a^2+b^2+4b^3+25a*b*c ;$
 instead of the lstlisting environment. 
    \end{document}
```

Note the verb like delimiters for lstinline. One thing however, the listings manual indicates verb like delimiters, but in all of my work I use the usual { and } and it works fine (maybe a quirk, but I find it easier to read and will continue using it as long as possible)

[image]

There are other ways also. For example the minted package does what you what, but it requires that you install Pygments, which is a Python library.

Comment: `\lstinline` has `\verb`-style delimiters: `\lstinline$f[a_,b_]:=a^2+b^2+4b^3+25a*b*c ;$`. The big difference is that it also has an optional keyval argument.

Comment: @rdhs: thanks for the correction. I edited the code. However, when I use { and } it works fine.

Comment: Why is there no syntax highlighting in the Mathematica code? I also see this for Mathematica, but not for other languages? Is it because the most recent version of Mathematica included in the `listings` package is 5.2, whereas Mathematica is currently at version 8?

Answer (score 14):

Use `\verb`, as in `\verb|f[a_,b_]:=a^2+b^2+4b^3+25a*b*c ;|`. For longer programs, use the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package. Or use Mathematica's *Save selection as PDF* feature and include the PDF as an image.

Answer (score 10):

To include an image of your Mathematica code, you can evaluate the cell

[image: Function in Mathematica 8]

and then select it (by clicking on the right square bracket `]`). Then, following the menu's `File`>`Save Selection As...` and saving as a PDF produces the PDF output:

[image]

One advantage of this approach is that it will include the embedded Mathematica font, as well as the same spacing and layout as in the actual Mathematica display. If you which to get rid of the input/output indicators, you can either clip the image using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `trim=lx ly ux uy,clip` key-value, or extract the image *before* it is evaluated.

Comment: Or, you could just click on the `In[1]` and hit Delete to get rid of it before saving to pdf.

Comment: Hahaha what? @QuantumDot

Comment: This answer is so underrated! I think is the best solution

Answer (score 6):

In addition to `lstlisting` solution, here is an alternative way of doing it.

In Mathematica, under *save as* menu, choose LaTex Document format, *.tex* and the code will be generated for you automatically.

For example, the following code

> [image: mathematica code]

will be converted to

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}

\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{f[\text{x$\_$}]\text{:=}\text{Exp}[-a*(x-y){}^{\wedge}2];}\\
\pmb{f\text{''}[x]}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(-2 a e^{-a (x-y)^2}+4 a^2 e^{-a (x-y)^2} (x-y)^2\)
\end{doublespace}

\end{document}
```

And the resulting document is like

> [image: mathematica code pdf]

If you would like it to be centered, use `\centerline` instead of `\noindent`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}

\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}

\begin{doublespace}
\centerline{$\pmb{f[\text{x$\_$}]\text{:=}\text{Exp}[-a*(x-y){}^{\wedge}2];}$}

\centerline{$\pmb{f\text{''}[x]}$}
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\centerline{$-2 a e^{-a (x-y)^2}+4 a^2 e^{-a (x-y)^2} (x-y)^2$}
\end{doublespace}

\end{document}
```

Comment: that's the LaTeX code. The question asks how to include the code.