# Fanciest way to include Mathematica code in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to include a Mathematica code in LaTeX. To obtain the Mathematica code I just exported notebook as PDF. I didn't like the way it was included in my TEX code so I just thought of adding a box around picture so as to make it a bit more fancy. It's not yet there but it's better than nothing. The code used is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\nonumber W_{r\rightarrow\infty}=&-\int_{r}^{\infty}\!F\,\mathrm{d}y=-    \int_r^\infty \!     \dfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \dfrac{q^2}{\alpha^2}     \dfrac{\alpha^3}{y^3}\left(1-    \dfrac{\alpha^2}    {y^2}\right)^{-2}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
=&-\dfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \dfrac{q^2}{\alpha^2}\alpha^3     \underbrace{\int_r^\infty     \! y^{-3} \left(1-\dfrac{\alpha^2}    {y^2}\right)^{-2} \,\mathrm{d}y}_{I} \label{eq:WcondI}
\end{align}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(15,5)
\color{blue}
\put(-1,0){\line(0,1){5}}
\put(0,1.5){\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{math}}
\put(-1,0){\line(1,0){15}}
\put(14,0){\line(0,1){5}}
\put(-1,5){\line(1,0){15}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

My output is

[image]

Any ideas on how to include Mathematica code in a more aesthetically way?

**Edit**:At first I used package `listing` but the problem was the fraction and the fact that I don't know how to include in a convenient way `In[1]` and `Out[1]`

Comment: Did you give a try with http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings

Comment: @texlearner: Thank you very much for your comment. I did actually but the problem is that the fraction in the answer is exported as a/b which is something I would like to avoid!

Comment: You could use `mathescape` - i'll extend my answer to that.

Comment: @Jubobs Where are thou?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I know this question is old and surely OP doesn't need it anymore, but recently I had similar problem and I think my solution answers the question.

First thing to note is that in Mathematica FrontEnd cells can have arbitrary styles. Each styles appearance is customizable by a stylesheet.
With default stylesheet even most basic cell styles i.e. `Input` and `Output` look different.

In cells with some styles (e.g `Input` or `Code`) code syntax is colored, this can be achieved using already mentioned in other answers `listings` package.

Cells with some styles (e.g. `Input`, `Output` or `Print`) by default use, so called `StandardForm`, which allows embedding of complicated formatting (fractions, superscripts etc.) inside code.
This was partially solved in other answers by using `mathescape` functionality of `listings` package.
Problem with this solution is that `mathescape` "completely escapes" to TeX. Since one can't nest `listings` environments/commands, I don't see a way to treat parts of escaped content again as code (e.g. typeset it verbatim) using `listings` only.

To achieve such functionality one can use `Verbatim` environment from `fancyvrb` package. By setting proper `commandchars` we can embed, for example, `\frac` command inside code, in such way that frac's arguments are typeset verbatim. Downside of `fancyvrb` is that it doesn't offer automatic syntax coloring. Fortunately `listings` has special interface to `fancyvrb` that allows combining of reading code by `fancyvrb` and typesetting it by `listings`.

Below I present usage of my [mmacells](https://github.com/jkuczm/mmacells) package, which implements solution based on `fancyvrb` + `listings` approach, with some additional features like customizable cell styles, automatic cell labels etc.

There's also corresponding *Mathematica* package: [CellsToTeX](https://github.com/jkuczm/MathematicaCellsToTeX), that automatically exports *Mathematica* code to TeX code compatible with `mmacells`. *Mathematica* package is described in detail in [answer to "How best to embed various cell groups into a latex project?" question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73589/14303)
on Mathematica Stack Exchange.

## Usage example

Print screen of result:
[image: Mathematica cells in pdf]

TeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{mmacells}


\mmaDefineMathReplacement[≤]{<=}{\leq}
\mmaDefineMathReplacement[≥]{>=}{\geq}
\mmaDefineMathReplacement[≠]{!=}{\neq}
\mmaDefineMathReplacement[→]{->}{\to}[2]
\mmaDefineMathReplacement[⧴]{:>}{:\hspace{-.2em}\to}[2]
\mmaDefineMathReplacement{∉}{\notin}
\mmaDefineMathReplacement{∞}{\infty}
\mmaDefineMathReplacement{}{\mathbbm{d}}


\mmaSet{
  morefv={gobble=2},
  linklocaluri=mma/symbol/definition:#1,
  morecellgraphics={yoffset=1.9ex}
}


\begin{document}

Input from question with output from my Mathematica version.
Input is in input form, it can be copied and pasted to Mathematica.
\begin{mmaCell}[functionlocal=y]{Code}
  Integrate[{y^(-3)*(1-(a/y)^2)^(-2)},{y,r,Infinity}]
\end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}{Output}
  \{ConditionalExpression[-\mmaFrac{1}{2 (\mmaSup{a}{2} - \mmaSup{r}{2})},
     Im[r] Re[a] ≠ Im[a] Re[r] || ((a + r > 0 || a + r ∉ Reals) &&
       ((Re[a] < r && Im[a] == 0) || a - r ∉ Reals)) || r ∉ Reals]\}
\end{mmaCell}

For comparison, same cells obtained by including PDFs exported from Mathematica:
% You need inCell.pdf and outCell.pdf files for this to work.
% \mmaCellGraphics{Input}{inCell}
% \mmaCellGraphics[yoffset=3.5ex]{Output}{outCell}

Same input expression, but in standard form (as if it was inputted using math assistant). Note that syntax coloring still works.
\begin{mmaCell}[index=3,functionlocal=y]{Input}
  \mmaSubSupM{\int}{r}{∞}\{\mmaFrac{1}{\mmaSup{y}{3}\mmaSup{\big(1-\mmaSup{\big(\mmaFrac{a}{y}\big)}{2}\big)}{2}}\}y
\end{mmaCell}


More features:
\begin{mmaCell}[
  moredefined=f,
  functionlocal=a,
  local=b,
  pattern={x_,x},
  excessargument=n,
  linkbuiltin=List
]{Code}
  (* A (* nested *) comment. *)
  Block[{a=3},a+2]
  f[x_]:=2x+1 
  Module[{b=c},
      Print["a string \" with double quotes inside ", b/d];
      b+1
  ]
  f[z]//FullForm
  Sin[m,n]
  List[1,List[2,3]]; (* Links to documentation. *)
\end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}{Output}
  5
\end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}{Print}
  a string " with double quotes inside \mmaFrac{c}{d}
\end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}[addtoindex=1]{Output}
  1+c
\end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}[form=FullForm]{Output}
  Plus[1,Times[2,z]]
\end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}[messagelink={message/General/argx}]{Message}
  Sin::argx: Sin called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>
\end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}{Output}
  Sin[m,n]
\end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}{Output}
  \{1,\{2,3\}\}
\end{mmaCell}
Graphics mixed with code:
\begin{mmaCell}{Code}
  a Graphics[{Green,Disk[]},ImageSize->50]/2
\end{mmaCell}
% You need greenDisk.pdf file for this to work.
% \begin{mmaCell}[moregraphics={moreig={scale=.7}}]{Output}
%   \mmaFrac{a \mmaGraphics{greenDisk}}{2}
% \end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}{Code}
  (* Different roles of one symbol. *)
  x;
  _x;
  \mmaDef{x_};
  \mmaPat{x_}->2x;
  \mmaPat{x_}:>2\mmaPat{x};
  f[\mmaPat{x_}]=2x;
  f[\mmaPat{x_}]:=2\mmaPat{x};
  Block[{\mmaFnc{x}},2\mmaFnc{x}];
  Module[{\mmaLoc{x}},2\mmaLoc{x}];
  \mmaUnd{Module}; (* undefined Module symbol *)
  \mmaLnB{Module}; (* Module symbol with link to documentation *)
  Sin[x\mmaExc{,x}];
\end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}[addtoindex=11]{Input}
  (* Nesting of "formatting boxes" *)
  \mmaSup{a}{\mmaSup{a}{a}} \mmaSub{a}{\mmaSub{a}{a}} \mmaSubSup{a}{\mmaSubSup{a}{a}{a}}{\mmaSubSup{a}{a}{a}} \mmaUnder{a}{\mmaUnder{a}{a}} \mmaOver{a}{\mmaOver{a}{a}} \mmaUnderOver{a}{\mmaUnderOver{a}{a}{a}}{\mmaUnderOver{a}{a}{a}} \mmaFrac{a}{\mmaFrac{a}{\mmaFrac{a}{a}}} \mmaSqrt{\mmaSqrt{a}} \mmaRadical{a}{\mmaRadical{a}{a}}
\end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}{Input}
  (* Replacements for infix operators in "Input" cells. *)
  x>=y; x<=y; x!=y; x->y; x:>y;
\end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}{Code}
  (* No replacement in "Code" cells. *)
  x>=y; x<=y; x!=y; x->y; x:>y;
\end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}[label={(\mmaCellIndex)custom}]{Code}
  (* Cell with custom label. *)
\end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}{Input}
  \mmaLnT{x}=2;(* labeled definition of x *)
\end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}{Input}
  \mmaLnL{x}(* usage of x with link to its definition *)
\end{mmaCell}

Implemented syntax elements:
\begin{mmaCell}[
  defined=defined,
  undefined=undefined,
  functionlocal=functionlocal,
  local=local,
  pattern=pattern,
  localconflict=localconflict,
  globalconflict=globalconflict,
  excessargument=excessargument,
  unknownoption=unknownoption,
  unwantedassignment=unwantedassignment,
  shadowing=shadowing,
  syntaxerror=syntaxerror,
  emphasizedsyntaxerror=emphasizedsyntaxerror,
  formattingerror=formattingerror,
]{Code}
  \mmaDef{Def} defined (*  defined symbol *)
  \mmaUnd{Und} undefined (* UndefinedSymbol *)
  \mmaFnc{Fnc} functionlocal (* FunctionLocalVariable *)
  \mmaLoc{Loc} local (* LocalVariable *)
  \mmaPat{Pat} pattern (* PatternVariable *)
  \mmaLCn{LCn} localconflict (* LocalScopeConflict *)
  \mmaGCn{GCn} globalconflict (* GlobalToLocalScopeConflict *)
  \mmaExc{Exc} excessargument (* ExcessArgument *)
  \mmaOpt{Opt} unknownoption (* UnknownOption *)
  \mmaAsg{Asg} unwantedassignment (* UnwantedAssignment *)
  \mmaShd{Shd} shadowing (* SymbolShadowing *)
  \mmaSnt{Snt} syntaxerror (* SyntaxError *)
  \mmaEmp{Emp} emphasizedsyntaxerror (* EmphasizedSyntaxError *)
  \mmaFmt{Fmt} formattingerror (* FormattingError *)
\end{mmaCell}

Inline cell: \mmaInlineCell[functionlocal=a]{Code}{Module[{a=5}, a]}.
Formatted inline cell:
\mmaInlineCell[pattern={x_,x}]{Input}{f[x_]:=\mmaFrac{\mmaSup{x}{2}}{5}}
\subsubsection*{
  Inline cell inside macro argument:
  \mmaInlineCellNonVerb[functionlocal=x]{Code}{Solve[\mmaSqrt{x}==y,x]}
}

\end{document}
```

## Unicode

There are three strategies of handling Unicode supported by `mmacells`. Code for all of them can be automatically generated by `CellsToTeX` *Mathematica* package.

#### 1. No Unicode

Don't use Unicode at all, use appropriate TeX commands instead.
This approach works in all engines.

`listings` package doesn't color elements provided by escaped commands, so they need to be wrapped with appropriate annotations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mmacells}
\begin{document}

\begin{mmaCell}{Input}
\mmaSub{x}{1} == \mmaFrac{-\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\beta}\)} \(\pmb{\pm}\) \mmaSqrt{\mmaSup{\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\beta}\)}}{2} - 4 \mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\alpha}\)} \mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\gamma}\)}}}{2 \mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\alpha}\)}}
\end{mmaCell}

\end{document}
```

[image: result of pdfLaTeX with Unicode]

#### 2. Unicode input

Use Unicode characters in input and automatically convert them to appropriate TeX commands by using `\mmaDefineMathReplacement`. This approach works in *pdfTeX* engine.

Replacements are implemented using `listings` `literate` option, so are "excluded" from automatic coloring, and identifiers containing Unicode characters need to be wrapped with appropriate annotations. Whether replacements will be used is controlled by `mathreplacements` option. By default `Code` cells don't use replacements (`mathreplacements=none`), `Input` cells use bold replacements (`mathreplacements=bols`) i.e. will use given command wrapped with math delimiters and `\pmb`, `Output`, `Print` and `Message` cells use "light" replacements (`mathreplacements=light`) i.e. will will use given command wrapped with math delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mmacells}
\begin{document}

\mmaDefineMathReplacement{±}{\pm}
\mmaDefineMathReplacement{α}{\alpha}
\mmaDefineMathReplacement{β}{\beta}
\mmaDefineMathReplacement{γ}{\gamma}

\begin{mmaCell}{Input}
\mmaSub{x}{1} == \mmaFrac{-\mmaUnd{β} ± \mmaSqrt{\mmaSup{\mmaUnd{β}}{2} - 4 \mmaUnd{α} \mmaUnd{γ}}}{2 \mmaUnd{α}}
\end{mmaCell}

\end{document}
```

[image: result of pdfLaTeX with Unicode]

#### 3. Unicode input and output

Use Unicode characters in input and rely on appropriate glyphs of used fonts. This approach works in Unicode-aware engines.

Since `listings` does not support Unicode, it needs to be switched off using `uselistings=false` option. With `listings` switched off no automatic coloring occurs, so all identifiers, also those not containing Unicode characters, need to be wrapped with appropriate annotations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mmacells}

\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}

\mmaSet{uselistings=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{mmaCell}{Input}
\mmaSub{\mmaUnd{x}}{1} == \mmaFrac{-\mmaUnd{β} ± \mmaSqrt{\mmaSup{\mmaUnd{β}}{2} - 4 \mmaUnd{α} \mmaUnd{γ}}}{2 \mmaUnd{α}}
\end{mmaCell}

\end{document}
```

[image: result of xelatex with Unicode]

Comment: This is a really nice solution!  Will you upload `mmacells` to CTAN?

Comment: @HenriMenke I planned to upload it, to CTAN, after adding documentation, but I don't know when I'll have time to do it.

Comment: Is there a way to have multiple local variables in a Code cell? For example when solving an equation to both x and y.

Comment: @Abby Sure, just use `functionlocal={x,y}` option.

Comment: @jkuczm Great solution! How would you update this with the new font seen in version 11, I think it's "source code pro".

Comment: @M.R. You can use `fv` option to pass `formatcom` key, with font changing commands, to `Verbatim` environment, on which `mmaCell` is based. Font changing commands [depend on used engine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/70587). So something like `\mmaSet{fv={formatcom*=\fontfamily{...}\selectfont}}` for pdfTeX, or `\mmaSet{fv={formatcom*=\setmonofont{...}\ttfamily}}` for XeTeX, or LuaTeX, where dots should be replaced with appropriate font name.

Comment: @jkuczm Is there a way to add a frame and gray background (as some do standard in lstings ?)

Comment: @Dominique You could use `tcolorbox` as [shown in issue 21](https://github.com/jkuczm/mmacells/issues/21#issuecomment-214266781).

Comment: Does this works with datasets too?

Comment: Would love to have this package added to the official sources. Any way that could happen?

Comment: Is there a way to prevent code inside a `mmaCell` from running to the edge of the page? It doesn't seem to respect the margins, or newlines

Comment: @pretzlstyle It seems one has to break lines manually.

Answer (score 20):

You could use `listings` together with `xcolor` to include the code, for example with this MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstset{language=Mathematica}
\lstset{basicstyle={\sffamily\footnotesize},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  numbersep=5pt,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos={t},
  frame={lines},
  rulecolor=\color{black},
  framerule=0.5pt,
  columns=flexible,
  tabsize=2
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=Mathematica,caption={Example code}]
    Integrate[{y^(-3)}*(1-(a/y)^2)^(-2),{y,r,Infinity}]
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

You would obtain something like [image: Code example image]

and by changing the `\lstset` even adapt the colors to look more `Mathematica`ish. You could then also use external code files and something like `\lstinputlisting{yourfile.m}` to include them. This is what i prefer, because then you could just (ok in Mathematica working on one cell) code the stuff you want and change the code. Due to the input it is then automatically the most recent version of your code example.

*Edit 1* The OP requested to use Math symbols and fractions in his code:

One way to do that is, to add `mathescape` to the lstset as a further key. Then at any `$` in the code the mode is switched to mathmode and one can type simply math. Then one could change the code line to

```
Integrate[{y^(-3)}*(1-$\bigl(\frac{a}{y}\bigr)$^2)^(-2),{y,r,Infinity}]
```

to obtain [image: Second Code with math]
though i think it is not that nice to read (because there's still `^2` in the code and other non-LaTeX-set formulae. Finally my remark above won't work anymore, this code would - of course - not be able to run in Mathematica anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The first thing I did was to use `listings` but if you see in my figure the answer contains a fraction which uses a horizontal line to separate numerator from denominator. If I use `listings` the result is something like `a/b`, with a slash instead of a horizontal line, that is... Another issue I am facing is the fact that I want to include `In[1]` and `Out[1]`. If I use `listings` those "keywords",which are different from actual keywords, are printed as part of the code...

Comment: Another issue I am facing is the fact that I want to include In[1] and Out[1]. If I use listings those "keywords",which are different from actual keywords, are printed as part of the code...

Comment: I'll think about that, but that's a tricky one. To Obtain `In[1]` instead of `1` (the number now printed as line number) would be possible i think, but alternating them (with `Out[...]`) is challenging.

Comment: @You are right about that, so I will edit my question in order to provide the information I forgot to include.

Comment: @Ronny, is there a way to make the comments in my code look grey in the latex file, instead of black? I want to make them easy to be distinguished from the rest of the code...

Comment: Haven't tested it, but if for ´Mathematica´ in ´lstlistings´ the Comments are well defined, adding `commentstyle=\color{yourgray}` to the styling should work (of course you have to define ´yourgray´ before.

Comment: What about cell brackets? Is there any way to preserve/include them? Thanks!

Comment: I have no direct idea how to do that. Could you maybe open a new topic for that explaining your problem with an MWE?

Answer (score 10):

Another way to include mathematica packages into latex is to use this package [mma.sty](http://kauers.de/software/mma/mma.sty)

by [Manuel Kauers](http://kauers.de/index.html). With

```
\usepackage{mma}
```

in the preamble one can do a lot. I find it really amazing. I normally enclose it in [mdframed](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed?lang=en) environment which I think is pretty cool. See the image below:

[image: MathematicaCodeInLaTeX]

There are also example on how one can use the package in the style file **mma.sty**.

**Addendum**

As requested by @KevinO'Bryant, I have added a MWE which produces the two images above.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} 
\usepackage{mma}
\newcommand{\bc}{\textcolor{blue}} 

% For mathematica session
\mdfdefinestyle{mmabox}{%
 innerlinewidth=0.5pt, innerleftmargin=10pt,%
 innerrightmargin=10pt, innertopmargin=10pt,%
 innerbottommargin=10pt, roundcorner=5pt,
 singleextra={\path (P) -- node[minimum height=.6cm,overlay,draw,fill=white, rounded corners,very thick] {\bf Mathematica Session} (O|-P);}
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=mmabox]{mma}


\begin{document}
 \begin{mma}
  \In |Command|[|arg|_1,1+1] \\
  \Out \mathrm{x^2+9} \\
  \In |quit| \\
  \Warning{name} something in text mode  \\
  \In |Print|["test"];\\
  \Print test\\
  \In |Quit| \\
  \Out {\rm
  \{ \{-6,\ \sqrt{2},\ \sqrt{3},\ k,\ 1 + n \},\ \{ \{k + n,\ 2 + k + n,\ -2\},\ \{ k + n,\ 5 + k + n,\ -5 \},\ \{2 + k + n,\ 5 + k + n,\ -3 \}  \} \} 
  } \\
\end{mma}

\begin{mma}
 \In {\mathrm{\bf f = \{ \sqrt{2}(\bc{n}+1)^{2}(\bc{n}+\bc{k}),\ 6 (\bc{n}+1) (-\bc{k} - \bc{n} - 2) \bc{k},\ \sqrt{-3}(\bc{k} + \bc{n} + 5)\};}} \\ 
 \In {\mathrm{\bf tower = \Big\{ \{\bc{k}, 1, 1 \},\ \Big\{\bc{h}, 1, \frac{1}{\bc{k} + 1} \Big\},\ \Big\{\bc{b}, \frac{\bc{n}-\bc{k}}{\bc{k}+1}, 0 \Big\} \Big\} ;}}\\
 \In {\mathrm{\bf ShiftPrimeEquivalentFactors[f,\ tower]}}\\
 \Out { 
 \mathrm{ 
  \{ \{-6,\ \sqrt{2},\ \sqrt{3},\ k,\ 1 + n \},\ \{ \{k + n,\ 2 + k + n,\ -2\},\ \{ k + n,\ 5 + k + n,\ -5 \},\ \{2 + k + n,\ 5 + k + n,\ -3 \}  \} \} 
 } 
 }\\
\end{mama}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is pretty cool. Mind sharing a MWE?

Comment: @KevinO'Bryant: I added a MWE as you requested.

Answer (score 8):

Using the `listings` package, it is possible to get math mode in the mathematica code. You need to add the `mathescape` option on the `listings` environment definition, and manually place the math delimiters in the listing. I realise that this may be impractical if you want to insert a lot of code.

I hope the following code makes my meaning clear.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!20}

\lstnewenvironment{mat}
{\lstset{language=mathematica,mathescape,columns=flexible}}
{}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\nonumber W_{r\rightarrow\infty}=&-\int_{r}^{\infty}\!F\,\mathrm{d}y=-    \int_r^\infty \!     \dfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \dfrac{q^2}{\alpha^2}     \dfrac{\alpha^3}{y^3}\left(1-    \dfrac{\alpha^2}    {y^2}\right)^{-2}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
=&-\dfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \dfrac{q^2}{\alpha^2}\alpha^3     \underbrace{\int_r^\infty     \! y^{-3} \left(1-\dfrac{\alpha^2}    {y^2}\right)^{-2} \,\mathrm{d}y}_{I} \label{eq:WcondI}
\end{align}

\begin{shaded}
\begin{mat}

In[1]:= Integrate[{y^(-3)*(1-(a/y)^2)^(-2)},{y,r,Infinity}]
Out[1]= {ConditionalExpression[$\displaystyle-\frac{1}{2(a^2-r^2)}$, Im[r] 
Re[a] $\neq$ Im[a] Re[r] || (( $a+r>0$ || $a+r \notin $ Reals) && ($a<r$ || 
$a-r \notin$ Reals) || $r\notin$ Reals )]}

\end{mat}

\end{shaded}

\end{document}
```

Note that I formatted the output manually. Here is the result:
[image: result]

Comment: Adding the ` Out[]` and `In[]` is of course easier, than the idea i just thought about, namely tweaking the numbering of the listing.

Comment: @Ronny Oops! I didn't see that you already mentioned the use of `mathescape`, sorry about that.

Comment: Actually i added that, when the OP mentioned that in his first comment below the Introduction, though i was too lazy to type the Output myself in math, i was a little faster with that additional edit than your post ;)