# How to include Maple code in LaTeX?

Tags: listings, code

At here [Fanciest way to include Mathematica code in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84748/fanciest-way-to-include-mathematica-code-in-latex) we can include Mathematica in LaTeX. 
I want to include the code

```
restart:
with(geom3d):
eqS:=Equation(sphere(S,(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 +(z-1)^2 -121=0,[x,y,z],'centername'=T)):
L:=[]:
for x from -5 to 10  do
for y from -5 to 10  do
for z from -5 to 10  do  if  x<>xcoord(T) and y<>ycoord(T) and z <> zcoord(T) and   type(x,integer) and type(y,integer)and type(z,integer) and eqS then
L:=[op(L), [x,y,z]] fi;
od: od: od: 
nops(L);
```

I tried

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Maple,caption={}]
restart:
with(geom3d):
eqS:=Equation(sphere(S,(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 +(z-1)^2 -121=0,[x,y,z],'centername'=T)):
L:=[]:
for x from -5 to 10  do
for y from -5 to 10  do
for z from -5 to 10  do  if  x<>xcoord(T) and y<>ycoord(T) and z <> zcoord(T) and   type(x,integer) and type(y,integer)and type(z,integer) and eqS then
L:=[op(L), [x,y,z]] fi;
od: od: od: 
nops(L);  
L;
\end{lstlisting}
```

How to include Maple code in LaTeX?

Comment: Can you include the information about the differences of Maple compared to Mathematica? It seems that same answers apply directly to any code up to style issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, Maple is not one of the predefined languages in `listings`. You have to create your own style for that.

Comment: I was wondering if its possible to [Matlab type publish/export](http://www.mathworks.com/help/rptgen/ug/presenting-matlab-code-and-results-to-others.html?searchHighlight=publish+latex) maple code into latex although not good.

Comment: This material may be helpful, or at least get you started: http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/support/?153

Answer (score 5):

Maplesoft provides a [LaTeX package](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=latex/viewing) that helps include Maple code into a LaTeX document. Unfortunately, it is quite bad I think. You have to modify the files yourself if you want to have the Maple commands in red for instance, and the output in blue.