# How to make my comments in the code grey in the latex doc?

Tags: pseudocode

I have to insert some mathematica code in my latex document. For that, I'm using the answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84748/fanciest-way-to-include-mathematica-code-in-latex) by user Ronny. Is it possible to add sth that would make my comments look grey in the resulting pdf document?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `commentstyle=\color{gray}`. Taking the code from answer linked by OP in the question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,framed,xcolor,amsmath}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!20}
\lstnewenvironment{mat}
{\lstset{language=mathematica,mathescape,columns=flexible,commentstyle=\color{gray}}}
{}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\nonumber W_{r     → ∞}=&-∫_{r}^{∞}\!F\,\mathrm{d}y=-    ∫_r^∞ \!     \dfrac{1}{4π\epsilon₀} \dfrac{q²}{\alpha²}     \dfrac{\alpha³}{y³}\left(1-    \dfrac{\alpha²}    {y²}\right)⁻²\,\mathrm{d}y\\
=&-\dfrac{1}{4π\epsilon₀} \dfrac{q²}{\alpha²}\alpha³     \underbrace{∫_r^∞     \! y⁻³ \left(1-\dfrac{\alpha²}    {y²}\right)⁻² \,\mathrm{d}y}_{I} \label{eq:WcondI}
\end{align}

\begin{shaded}
\begin{mat}
In[1]:= Integrate[{y^(-3)*(1-(a/y)²)^(-2)},{y,r,Infinity}]
Out[1]= {ConditionalExpression[$\displaystyle-\frac{1}{2(a²-r²)}$, Im[r]
Re[a] $     ≠     $ Im[a] Re[r] || (( $a+r>0$ || $a+r      ∉      $ Reals) && ($a<r$ ||
$a-r      ∉     $ Reals) || $r     ∉     $ Reals )]} (* this is a comment *)
\end{mat}
\end{shaded}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!

Would you mind taking a look also at this question of mine? ;) 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214300/including-mathematica-code-in-book-type-document