# How to include Mathematica code in LaTeX/Beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting, wolfram-mathematica

I found the best (IMHO) way to include Mathematica code in LaTeX: [Fanciest way to include Mathematica code in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84748/fanciest-way-to-include-mathematica-code-in-latex/223898#223898) (@jkuczm)

To the test I put the TeX code from link above, but it doesn't work with Beamer presentation. File can't be compiled. I get many errors like this:

```
Integrate[{y^(-3)*(1-(a/y)^2)^(-2)},{y,r,Infinity}] \end {mmaCell} \begin \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \FV@BeginScanning was complete.


! LaTeX Error: \begin{list} on input line 45 ended by \end{beamer@framepauses}.

! Missing } inserted.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

! LaTeX Error: \begin{list} on input line 45 ended by \end{beamer@frameslide}.

! LaTeX Error: \begin{list} on input line 45 ended by \end{document}.

! You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.

! LaTeX Error: \begin{list} on input line 45 ended by \end{document}.

! Emergency stop.
```

Any ideas on how to include Mathematica code in Beamer?

**Edit:** It was enough to use fragile frame. Thanks for @samcarter

Comment: Can you make a complete compilable document?

Comment: Did you use a `fragile` frame?

Comment: I didn't use a `fragile` frame. Thank you for a suggestion. I'll try it for a while.

Comment: Great! It works fine. I would like to thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragile code, such as `listings` have to be used in

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\end{frame}
```