# Mathematica code for Beamer in LaTeX

Tags: beamer, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to include a Mathematica code in Beamer. I tried `lstlisting` and `verbatim` environments but I am not satisfied with the outcome. A fancy way to include Mathematica code in LaTeX has been introduced here: [Fanciest way to include Mathematica code in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84748/fanciest-way-to-include-mathematica-code-in-latex/223898). Nevertheless, this approach does not seem to work in beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{media9}
\usetheme{Madrid}
```

(above there is my pramble). Any ideas on how to include Mathematica code in a fancy way?

Mathematica code:

```
sequence := "all work and no play makes jack a dull boy"
(sequence <> # & /@ NestList["y" <> # &, "y", 10])
ListLinePlot[ N /@ Entropy /@ (sequence <> # & /@ NestList["y" <> # &, "y", 
10]),  Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.02], PlotTheme -> "Web", 
ImageSize -> Medium, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 
14, Black] & /@ {"y Redundancy", "Entropy"})]
```

Comment: Please add a compilable code!

Comment: Fancyness is subjective. “Not working in beamer” is not and it means you tried. We need to see what you tried and how it failed to be able to help you.

Comment: If you use `mmacells` package in beamer you must use `\begin{frame}[fragile]`.