# What is the most precise way of including a Mathematica code in a LaTeX document?

Tags: page-breaking, page-numbering, pdfpages, wolfram-mathematica

I have tried to insert my Mathematica notebook into LaTeX by converting it as a PDF file and then using `\includepdf[pages=1-4]{blablabla.pdf}`. However, there are now two problems I faced:

1. This code sample should be in the beginning of an Appendix chapter. But when I use the code `\chapter{blablabla}` and then the above command `\includepdf`, the code automatically starts from another page. Thus, **an unwanted one page break occurs in my document and I don't know how to solve this.**
2. Although all the numbers in my documents are numbered in order, these pages inserted from PDF appears without numbers. This again breaks my usual layout in the document. So **what is the proper way of numbering pages in that case?**

Besides these problems, for future reference, **I want to know the most reliable way of inserting a Mathematica code in LaTeX.**

Comment: Related: [How can I include Mathematica code in a document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42380) and [Fanciest way to include Mathematica code in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84748)

Comment: Before asking the question, I took a glance at these questions. They indeed answer my last question but I didn't see anything that can possibly answer first two. What should I do to organize my document in the case I use `\includepdf`? That's what I am actually looking for.

Comment: I solved the problem about page numbers from a previous question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21248/71530).

Now, all left is to deal with the page breaking. I wonder if it is possible to  make LaTeX resize the inserted PDF document so that I shrink it somehow and it fits to the first page, just under the chapter name.

Comment: what `\includepdf` does is insert the whole page(s) of the specified PDF literally into the document. This necessitates a page break before the pages are inserted. The default `pagecommand` (`pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}`) causes no page numbers on the inserted pages; you can change this key if you want numbers. But I posted those links because I think those methods are really better than this method. With `\includepdf`, the style of the included code will not match the rest of your document, so IMO these other methods are "more reliable".

Comment: I understand but still I want to try my luck by asking the same question to Mathematica forum. Maybe there could be a way to rearrange the PDF output of the notebooks so that they look better and save more space. Thanks for your help. If I fail, I will (and I have to, indeed) try the answers you linked above.

Comment: Have you more infos here or is the problem solved? How?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you do not want to insert complete pages but rather just include the mathematica pages as images, for which you can use `\includeraphics` and just scale with `[width=...]` as for other images.

If it is *code* that you are wanting to include you may be better including it as text using listings or minted or some other code highlighting package.